# Why Symfony2 dont catch exceptions

Tags: php, symfony, exception

i have a repository

```
class TurnoRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findTurnoActivo()
    {
        $q = $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->where('t.activo = :activo')
            ->setParameter('activo', true)
            ->getQuery();

        return $q->getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

this method throw a NoResultException but if i try to catch in my controller

```
private function obtenerTurno()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $turno = null;

    try {
        $turnoActivo = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Turno')->findTurnoActivo();
    } catch (NoResultException $e) {
        return false;
    }

    return $turno;
```

}

always i get 500 Internal Server Error on my page

Comment: Run your application in `dev` environment, to see what's the exact error message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Symfony2 code is namespaced so you have to add the correct namespace for the class `NoResultException`,  try using:

```
catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e)
```

Note the backslash in front of the Doctrine namespace or import the `NoResultException` class by using `use`.

Comment: yeah i forget the `use Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException;`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$q->getOneOrNullResult();` if you don't want to catch `NoResultException` in the controller.

Comment: I prefer the exception, for business logic