# symfony2 kernel intercept my exception

Tags: symfony, exception

I've a try-catch statement code inside an action of a controller:

```
public function MyAction(){
    ...
    try{
    ...
    }
    catch(MyException $e){
    ...
   }
   ....
}
```

But the exception is intercepted by symfony, show me the twig template of exception detected. It means my catch statemant is never executed, right?

Why? (inside the `try` i'm just calling a method of another object)

What's wrong?

How Can I do symfony execute my own exceptions?

(I think it's really strange, beacuse it's similar the try-catch em->persist/flush)

Comment: Does this apply to your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229120/why-symfony2-dont-catch-exceptions?rq=1

Comment: Are you sure your catch  statement is catching the correct class name from the correct namespace? What happens when you also catch \Exception in a separate catch?

Comment: try to catch also catch(\Exception $e) - what instance of $e is there?

Comment: catch the \Exception $e is caught correctly.
Ok thx you all.
php did not find MyExceptionClass, because I've not use neither the full path or the use statement.
thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just forgot the use statetament or the full namespace path and so php can't find MyExceptionClass.

resolve as

```
catch(path\to\MyException $e){...}
```

or

```
use path\to\MyException;
....
...
catch(MyException $e){
```