# Catching doctrine exception Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, try-catch

How can i catching a doctrine exception ? 
I am trying the code found here : 
[How to catch Exception in symfony 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325746/how-to-catch-exception-in-symfony-2)
[Why Symfony2 dont catch exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229120/why-symfony2-dont-catch-exceptions)
But that doesn't work.

Code :

```
try{

    $emOperateur->flush();                      
    return $this->redirect($request->getUri());

}catch(\Doctrine\ORM\ORMException $e){

    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Blablablabla');
}
```

When i insert a tuple with same primary key, that doesn't go in catch and i have a screen with classic error message.

Comment: What exception do you expect to be thrown? Maybe the type of exception you want is different. I mean are you sure that the doctrine throws an exception?

Comment: Try to catch \Exception

Comment: Afaik, these kind of exceptions are thrown in `->persist(...)` not in `->flush()`. What happends if you put the try..catch construction around the `->persist(...)` call?

Comment: Try catching ```\Exception $e``` If doctrine throws an error you will know if it does + the exact error class

Answer (score 2):

On a related note, you should check for things like duplicate primary keys first (you can use the doctrine validator), because if you DO receive a doctrine exception the entity manager will have closed and you won't be able to recover from it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to catch \Exception

```
try{
    ...
 }catch(\Exception e){
    echo($e->getMessage());
 }
```